# Adding Categories to Getting Started with Rails tutorial, get "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I followed  Getting Started with Rails tutorial tutorial, created the articles and comments MVCs and wanted to add category tags to my app. I repeated the steps from the tutorial (creating comments) and had categories up and running (can create and view categories via articles/show.html.erb). However, when I tried to add a partial for viewing all the categories that has been created and use the partial on the home page (articles/index.html.erb) i get the following error

```
Showing /Users/szymonborucki/ruby_apps/workspace/newspaper/app/views/articles/_sidebar_categories.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #2):

  <h2>Browse by categories: </h2>
  <% @categories.each do |c| %>
    <p><%= c.category %></p>
  <% end %>
```

Here is the partial (_sidebar_categories.html.erb)

```
 <h2>Browse by categories: </h2>
    <% @categories.each do |c| %>
      <p><%= c.category %></p>
    <% end %>
```

categories_controller.rb

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @categories = Category.all   
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @category = @article.categories.create(category_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

   def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @category = @article.categories.find(params[:id])
    @category.destroy
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end
  private
    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:category)
    end
end
```

Category.rb model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end
```

Articles index.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Listing articles</h1>


    <% @articles.each do |article| %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <h2><%= article.title %></h2> 
        </div>
      </div> <!-- .row -->

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <p><%= article.content %></p> 
        </div>
      </div> <!-- .row -->

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <!-- <ul class="list-unstyled"> -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><%= link_to 'Show', article %></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg"><%= link_to 'Delete', article, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></button>

        </div>
      </div> <!-- .row -->

    <% end %>
    </div> <!-- .container -->

<% content_for :aside do %>
  <%= render 'sidebar_popular' %>
  **<%= render 'sidebar_categories' %>**
<% end %>
```

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're in `/articles` it's hitting the `ArticlesController`.

Either define `@categories` there or in a `before_filter` in your `ApplicationController`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using any named scope (or any other filter) for your categories, I guess the simplest of solutions for your scenario would be just to change in your partial, this:

```
<% @categories.each do |c| %>
```

to that:

```
<% Category.all.each do |c| %>
```

As very well Baloo points out, in order to use instance variables (eg @category) or collections (eg @categories) you have to define them first, either in your controller (articles_controller in this case) or in the view itself (not too Rails-ie, but it works)